# Quality of webcam affects Computer Vision?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, video-capture, webcam-capture

I am new with OpenCV and Computer Vision and at the moment I am working on a program which needs to find circles while capturing videos.

I am using OpenCV for Python with the class *HoughCircles* to find the needed shape.

I actually need to capture the video from a webcam because it needs to be perpendicular to the horizontal sheet of paper where I am inserting circles.

However, when I try to capture the video from this webcam (Tecknet around 10£-12$), other than recognise only the needed circles it displays additional hundreds. I've compared this with my Macbook Pro webcam, which recognises perfectly the circles on the video.

Before I proceed on working on this, I'd like to have a feedback from you guys, as I am a beginner and I thought that any webcam could be ok.

Is it actually the quality of the webcam? Is it the class I am using in OpenCV or there can be other factors such as light conditions that can influence?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can be any of your hints or even another problem. My crystal ball is in maintenance... HoughCircles is quite sensitive to parameters, maybe you should try to adjust them.

Comment: Thank you @Micka, I'll research on this function!